# joining a table with 4 other table laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There are 5 tables like `Doctor` table having`(id,name,city_id,country_id,insurance_id,speciality_id)`, `city` table`(id,name,country_id)`, `country` table`(id,name)`, `insurance` table`(id,name)`, `speciality` table`(id,name)` and `doctor_insurance` table`(id,doctor_id,insurance_id)`.

Relationship is as follows:-

doctor `belongsTo` City and City `hasMany` Doctor , 
doctor `belongsTo` speciality and speciality `hasMany` Doctor , 
City `belongsTo` Country and Country `hasMany` City  , 
doctor `belongsToMany` insurance and insurance  `belongsTOMany` Doctor.

How do I get the list of `doctor where city=NewYork, Country=USA, Insurance=United Health Care and Speciality= Dentist`?

Answer (score 2):

you can query like this,

```
$result=DB::table("doctor as do")
->leftjoin('city  as ci', 'ci.id', '=', 'do.city_id')
->leftjoin("country as co","co.id","=","do.country_id")
->leftjoin("insurance as in","in.id","=","do.insurance_id")
->leftjoin("speciality as sp","sp.id","=","do.speciality_id")
->select('*')
->where('ci.name', '=', 'NewYork')
->where('co.name', '=', 'USA')
->where('in.name', '=', 'United Health Care')
->where('sp.name', '=', 'Dentist')
->get();
```

Comment: thanx for your answer. But got an error

 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ci.name' in 'where clause' .

Comment: that is just way to do. you can change as per your database table and field name.

Comment: Just did same as u told. By still got d same. Is there any other way.

Comment: print your query. and let me know what it built form given.

Comment: and also some demo data from tables to refer.

Comment: if i comment all the insurance line in left join and where clause then I am getting the details.
And insurance to doctor has many to many relation so that's why it isn't working.What should i do get the details with doctor and insurance.

Comment: use inner join in insurance <==> doctor. it return all matching data from both.

Comment: Can you please help me out with that. Still got stuck in it.

Comment: ->join("insurance as in","in.id","=","do.insurance_id") change this.